# Accidentally turned on TalkBack, how do I turn it off?

Tags: accessibility, talk-back

I accidentally turned on TalkBack in the Accessibility menu. When I turned it on, I got some kind of walkthrough on how to use it. I couldn't cancel it. So I turned off my phone.

When I turned it back on again, it took me 15 minutes to unlock my phone. Apparently I had to touch a button to give it focus and then double-tap it to click it.

Now my question is: how do I turn this off? I can't reach the settings because I don't know how to access a dropdown and I can't scroll through all my apps.

Comment: Related: [Scrolling with talkback on](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112919/how-to-scroll-screen-when-using-text-to-speech).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow, I could get into the Settings menu by turning aeroplane mode on and starting Google Maps (which is on my home screen). Google Maps then sends you to Settings. In there, I can scroll using three fingers.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with LG Android also - accidentally turned ON talkback. Here's how I got it turned off.

- You can swipe by using two fingers
- Tap once on Settings
- Then double-tap on Settings to activate
- Repeat process on the following
- General/Accessibility/Vision
- In Vision, you should see TalkBack where you can turn it off (again by using the same single, then double-tapping process)

Answer (score 1):

My fix:

1. Press Google Assistant button on phone, button below volume up/down button on LG V40 phone on left side, starts Google assistant.
2. State "Open Settings"
3. Double press on general, then "Accessibility" then "Hearing" then turn off "TalkBack"

Answer (score 0):

1. Double tap on the "Green" square that appears with a voice in the background.
2. It's difficult to navigate with this TalkBack option, but follow the "double tap" procedure and reach "TalkBack" feature which is "ON".
3. Same double tap, you'd be able to turn off "TalkBack".

Answer (score 0):

If Google Assistant is enabled and "Ok Google" trigger is set up, try the following voice command:

> Ok Google, turn off TalkBack and flip the switch