# How to scroll screen when using text-to-speech accessibility?

Tags: text-to-speech, accessibility

Under normal circumstances a swipe will cause controls in the Android UI to scroll. Such as swiping the home screen will get to the next screen. Swiping a list will scroll the list. The swiping functionality is disabled when text-to-speech is on.

My particular situation is that I'm trying to turn off text-to-speech. However to do this, I need to scroll through the settings page to get to the Accessibility settings. But I don't know how to scroll!

So the question is: how can one scroll through screens and lists in the Android UI when text-to-speech is enabled? or more succinctly, how to turn off text to speech in Android?

Answer (score 3):

When text to speech is enabled, two finger swipe will swipe the screen to navigate between screens and scroll lists.