# Pixel 3A Android 10 Assistant auto comes on and stops gesture, unable to reset connected devices

Tags: settings, operating-system, google-pixel, android-10

I have a brand new Pixel 3A with the recently updated Android 10 update.

Google Assistant has been activated while in my laptop bag.

I'm assuming this is because of the incessant urgings that Google displays on screen, and of course the new android doesn't swictch the screen off when you hit the power button, it leaves an 'awake' screen that can respond. Well, however it happened, Assistant is enabled and it is causing a number of problems, and I can't switch it off.

### The main issues are:

- Assistant repeats continuously on the arcane workings of the system. Voice messages like 'Checking WebAPP for updates' 'Downlaoding update' '10% downloaded, etc'
- Assistant stops the phone Whenever **any** event status changes Examples of this are 'Home screen 1of 2, double tap to enable' etc., etc., etc totally take over the user interface.
- The UI is now a triple tap pause system. To do anything, you tap an icon and wait for it to be highlighted (at which point a stream of help instructions are played back) then double tap to activate. This happens for **each and every tap** including back buttons, home buttons, whatever.The system is now an incredibly slow, novice system.
- **The gesture system is disabled**. This is the real killer. Without the gesture system you are locked into only what is visible. You cant get into the app drawer, for instance. And you can't get beyond the displayed items in the settings screens.

### **My Problem is:**

The instructions to switch off assistant are as follows:

- Open the google app
- Tap the compass at the bottom right
- Tap the profile button top right
- Tap the Assistant
- Scroll down to the Assistant devices,Devices section and switch off.

  ***BUT* gestures and scrolling are disabled**

You can see to the Face Match setting, but connected devices is somewhere way, way down below that. And one can't get there. Not for love nor money.

Under Android 9, I could deactivate with a voice command.

That seems to be gone.

Is my only solution to do a factory re-set?

Anyone out there with a solution for me?

Comment: The whole description looks like the [TalkBack accessibility feature](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/6007123), not Google Assistant. Related: [Accidentally turned on talkback](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38585) and [How to scroll screen when using text-to-speech accessibility?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112919)

Comment: Thank you Andrew T., that was the the solution. Two fingered swipe.